# Add-on not compatible with Firefox upon .xpi install attempt

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, xpi

I'm trying to publish my first Firefox extension and having trouble installing it.

I sign the package with `jpm xpi`. However, when I try to install the *.xpi* file, I get the error:

```
[extension name] could not be installed because it is not compatible with Firefox Developer Edition 52.0a2
```

I have also tried this in the consumer Firefox version 50.0.

Current `em` tags:

`<em:minVersion>0.9</em:minVersion>
 <em:maxVersion>1.0+</em:maxVersion>`

I have also tried

```
 '<em:maxVersion>50.0.*</em:maxVersion>'
```

And

```
 '<em:maxVersion>52.0+</em:maxVersion>'
```

---

My current XPI file is hosted [here](http://stopnormalizing.com/snfirefox/snfirefox.xpi)

---

```
`<?xml version="1.0"?>

<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">

  <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
  <em:id>lets@stopnormalizing.com</em:id>
    <em:version>1.1</em:version>

<!-- Target Application this extension can install into,
         with minimum and maximum supported versions. -->

<em:targetApplication>
    <Description>
      <!-- Firefox's UUID -->
      <em:id>[myemail]</em:id>
      <em:minVersion>0.9</em:minVersion>
      <em:maxVersion>1.0+</em:maxVersion>
    </Description>
  </em:targetApplication>

  <!-- Front End MetaData -->
  <!-- My_Theme -->
  <em:name>Stop Normalizing</em:name>
  <em:description>my extension description</em:description>
  <em:creator>my name</em:creator>
  <em:homepageURL>my url</em:homepageURL>
<!-- 
  <em:aboutURL>my website URL</em:aboutURL>

  <!-- Front End Integration Hooks (used by Theme Manager)-->
    <em:internalName>Extension_name</em:internalName>
  </Description>

</RDF>`
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated. I'm at a loss for how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a Firefox Add-on SDK extension. The *install.rdf* should be automatically generated for you when you execute `jpm xpi` from your [*package.json*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json) file. The *install.rdf* file that is shown above appears to have been copied from [the example on this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Themes/Obsolete/Creating_a_Skin_for_Firefox/install.rdf) and then edited by hand. In other words, it does not appear to have been automatically generated using `jpm xpi`. As such, it has errors.

### Allow `jpm xpi` to automatically create a new *install.rdf*

You probably have that hand edited *install.rdf* file (and perhaps a *bootstrap.js* file) in the directory in which you ran `jpm xpi`. I suggest you remove the *install.rdf* (and *bootstrap.js* if it exists) from the directory in which you ran `jpm xpi` and permit it/them to be automatically generated by `jpm xpi` from your *package.json*.  To have substantially the same information in the new *install.rdf*, you will need to add, or change, the following in your *package.json*:

```json
"title": "Stop Normalizing Alt Right",
"fullName": "Stop Normalizing",
"version": "1.1.0",
"id": "lets@stopnormalizing.com",
"homepage": "http://www.stopnormalizing.com",
"author": "George Zola",
```